# Dynamic Generics in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In my DB I have different documents:

```
interface Dog {
    name: string;
}
interface Cat {
    character: string;
}

interface Person {
    wealth: number;
}

interface Data{
    dog:Dog,
    cat:Cat,
    person:Person,
}
```

And depend on the document name I want to get the document type:

```
const getStuffFromDb = (type:string):Data.dog|Data.cat|Data.person{
    return apiCall(type);
}

for (const item of ["dog", "cat", "person"]) {
    getStuffFromDb(item);
}
```

How knowing the name "dog", "cat" or "person", I can infer the type `getStuffFromDb` returns? What should I put instead of `Data.dog|Data.cat|Data.person` or how this should look like in the first place?

`Data.dog|Data.cat|Data.person` is a pseudocode to represent idea, hope it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type` parameter should be [restricted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to known keys of `Data`, then it will be possible to [lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) value type of this key:

```js
const getStuffFromDb = <T extends keyof Data>(type: T): Data[T] => {
    return apiCall(type);
}

const foo = getStuffFromDb("cat") // foo is Cat
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsDmyDeAoZQ5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUTAbjwF89RJZEUBhOMXASIIAFnCiJOVWvRBNWeduGjwkyAArRq6EIKLIA7hDgAbMCKogArqQBG0ZmyWdVKVPzh6iAEyxUMmAA0QoQI-FR8YMH6AA5aOlSaUNogwU5gAJ5xaOgIAHJkKAC8yADWEBnoMGgeit4QCCbiKDBWIAhgwDrIcDHAfCYmABSZcdJ0DACUVHAgGYoIOrTImBBgAMpgVjAwAGJQ6KSotsglADwAKsgQAB6QIN7UZRVVNWBwAHwjWZTIF9NvOAAbQuAF1Th8vIQoGsrFBdL1%20qZhqMIJNHAslgIYOh0KcVmtNts9gcjrYhgAiMJgCmTZAAenpyBxeOAT0iihxUGQQ0WIGWwEgpGQryBFN8mApgWQVP4UplcWSOgp4LgTz5tDp%20H0qw2Wx2%200OxyGgogpHRrCAA)

Comment: that's insane, but it works